# Rewrite htaccess foo.com/username

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to have it so `foo.com/userinfo.php?user="username"` will be re-written as `foo.com/username`. I have gotten this to work using `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ userinfo.php?user=$1` in my htaccess. However, when a slash is added to the end of the username such as `foo.com/username/` it just redirects it to `foo.com/userinfo.php?user="username"`. While this does pull up the profile it doesn't look as well in the url bar. Thank you for any help!

Here is my `.htaccess` code now

```
RewriteEngine On    

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ userinfo.php?user=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `/?' as the expression "the character / or nothing".

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ userinfo.php?user=$1
```

Comment: When I do this it works, however, it removes all images and any styling!

Comment: Then you most likely need to accept relative entries as well `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(/.+))$ userinfo.php?user=$1` or similiar